# Can't echo anything after an html button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, contact-form

I'm making a website and need a contact page that emails me when people press send. I have three files, a contactus.html, which includes the form and a send button, a contact.js, which uses jquery to verify that all the boxes in the contactus.html are filled out, and a contact_process.php file which sends an email to me after the send button is clicked. So far, the code mostly works and an email is sent to me every time, as well as that if someone tries to send it without filling out all the forms, they are not able to, but I want to echo something after the mail is sent to tell the user that their message was received.

I used this code, which sends the email but doesn't echo anything afterward (you might notice that this form technically allows someone to type nothing in at all and still press send, however, my contact.js verifies whether or not the contact form is empty).

```
<?php
// Send email
if (isset($_POST['message']) and isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['email']) and 
isset($_POST['number']) and isset($_POST['subject'])) {

$message = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$subject_of_sender = $_POST['subject'];
$to = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "New Email"; // Email Subject
$body = "You have recieved a message from: $name\n Subject: $subject_of_sender \n Email: $email \n Phone Number: $number \n Message: \n $message";

$headers = "From: email@domain.com";

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);   

if ($send) {
     echo 'thanks';    // This is where it won't echo anything
} else {
     echo 'error';
}
}

?>
```

Is there any way to make it so that after the "send" button is clicked, a message echos to the user? Here is my contactus.html (this is just a snippet of the code to only include the form)

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
                    <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control valid" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name (Required)'" placeholder="Enter your name (Required)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control valid" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address (Required)'" placeholder="Email (Required)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control valid" name="number" id="number" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your phone number (Required)'" placeholder="Enter your phone number (Required)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject (Required)'" placeholder="Enter Subject (Required)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message (Required)'" placeholder=" Enter Message (Required)"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm boxed-btn">Send</button>

                        </div> 
                      </form>
                     </div>
```

and my contact.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($) {
    "use strict";


jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value)
}, "type the correct answer -_-");

// validate contactForm form
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
            },
            subject: {
                required: true,
            },
            number: {
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "You must enter a name.",
            },
            subject: {
                required: "You must enter a subject.",
            },
            number: {
                required: "You must enter a phone number.",
            },
            email: {
                required: "You must enter a email."
            },
            message: {
                required: "You must enter a message.",
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url:"contact_process.php",
                success: function() {
                    $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                        $('#success').fadeIn()
                        $('.modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#success').modal('show');
                    })
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                        $('#error').fadeIn()
                        $('.modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#error').modal('show');
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})     
})(jQuery)
})
```

Comment: Did you not close off your form? I don't see `</form>` anywhere and even when going into edit mode.

Comment: FWIW, you shouldnt rely on client side validation for your form, your backend should also validate that the required inputs are present

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I did, I just accidentally left it out of the code I pasted here, I've updated it now.

Comment: @WesleySmith   My contact.js verifies that all fields are filled out, should I remove the beginning `if (isset($_POST['message']) and isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['email']) and 
isset($_POST['number']) and isset($_POST['subject']))` from my php

Comment: Ok thanks. Well, if this is a JS problem, I'm not the guy for it. On the PHP side of things, check to see if error reporting shows anything.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner honestly I honestly don't even know where the issue is coming from, everything seems to work fine and the email is sent, but it just won't echo the message

Comment: Echoing something from php to an ajax request isn't enough to make that response display on the page that sent the ajax request. that's... just not how ajax works.

Comment: @KevinB what do you suggest I do then

Comment: Researching ajax would be a good start, though you could also just copy paste the answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would return json like this:

```
if ($send) {
      $success = 1;
      $message = 'Some success message';
} else {
      $success = 0;
      $message = 'Some error message';
}
$data = [
   'success' => $success,
   'message' => $message ,
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then change my success handler to something like:

```
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
        $('#success').fadeIn()
        // show response.message in the html somewhere
    } else {
        $('#error').fadeIn()
        // show response.message in the html somewhere     
    }
    // ... other stuff...
  },
```

The main point being that when you echo the data from the php script, the ajax calling js needs to check the response and do something with it. I chose to echo json instead of just a string message because I think its cleaner, though you could do either.

See [this article](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/) for more info on this approach.